# send a json from one component to another without being seen in the url of the target component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to send a json from componentA to componentB. The problem is that the json appears in the url. How can I make the json not appear?

routing

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'componentA', component: componentA},
  {path: 'componentB', component: componentA, data : {}},
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
];
```

template componentA

```
<a *ngFor="let item aArray" (click)="fn_sendJson(item)">Send jSON</a>
```

componentA .ts

```
this.aArray={"name":"pablo","countrys":["colombia","perú"],"lastname":"ramirez"}
.
.
fn_sendJson(item:any){
 this.router.navigate(['componentB', {"data": JSON.stringify(item)}]);
}
```

ComponentB .ts

```
constructor(
 private router : Router,
 private route: ActivatedRoute
 ) {
 sub:any;
 jsonReceived:any
 . 
 .
 this.sub = this.route.params
 .subscribe(v => this.jsonReceived =JSON.parse(v.data));
```

I have not found a way to avoid converting the original json to a string, I would like to know if there is an effective method of sending such as the json, and get it without needing it to be present in the url. Thank you

Comment: You can use shared service to share the data from one component to another. or use `JSON.stringify(your_json)` to stringify the data and `JSON.parse(val)` to parse it

Comment: @SachinGupta I'm something new, the first way is to send a json from one component to another without having to show it in the url? (reason why I asked the question). The second way is the one that I put in the example that currently works for me.

Comment: you can create one service on that service we have one variable which is storing a json and when `componentB` is rendered we are accessing the data from that service. so there is no need to pass the json data from query param.

Comment: See how to share data between components. https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/
Also read about Angular services https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4.

Comment: Why don't you use ```{skipLocationChange: true}``` in your router.navigate??

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur for what? what is the function?

Comment: @yavg, It will Navigates without changing the url at top, hence your data will not be visible at the url but you will be redirected as usual like now, just try for it, for reference : https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to send some complex data from one component to another, it is usually not a good practice to to send it through the url. What you can do is create a service like this:

**sharing.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharingService {
  private sharingObject: any;
  constructor() { }

  get sharingValue() {
    return this.sharingObject
  }

  set sharingValue(obj) {
    this.sharingObject = obj;
  }
}
```

Now you need to inject that service in both of your components in order to sharing data between them.

First component will look like this:

**first.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharingService} from '../sharing.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css']
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
  myJson: any;
  constructor(private sharingService: SharingService, private router: Router) {
    this.myJson = {
      a: "hello",
      b: "World"
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  send() {
    this.sharingService.sharingValue = this.myJson;
    this.router.navigate(['/second'])
  }

}
```

Now in your second component, you can access the value set by first component

**second.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharingService} from '../sharing.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-second',
  templateUrl: './second.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./second.component.css']
})
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {
  myJson: any;
  constructor(private sharingService: SharingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.myJson = this.sharingService.sharingValue;
  }

}
```

Here is the working stacklitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7wa4qx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsecond%2Fsecond.component.ts) for this approach

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`data service`** like below

first, create one service in that

```
  share: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  share$: Observable<any> = this.share.asObservable();
```

and then define one method

```
shareDate(data:object){
 this.share.next(data);
}
```

In the **`component A`**

```
fn_sendJson(item:any){
 this.router.navigate(['componentB']);
 this.serviceName.shareDate({"data": JSON.stringify(item)})
}
```

and in the **`component B`** you can access the data like below

```
ngOnInit() {
this.serviceName.share$.subscribe(
  res=>{
        console.log(res)//you will get the data
    }
  }
```

Hope it will solve your problem!

Comment: thanks, I have many questions... should I create them in a provider, no? what is the "$" symbol for, it excuses so much ignorance but it is not clear to me the difference between share and share $? and what is this.share.next (data) for ?;

Comment: `$` notations are used to indicate the `Observable`. When the new value gets this.share.next (data) , it will emit that value, that value you are subscribing the value .